# How to protect removal of a subfolder (namely .git folder) via ACL?

Tags: permissions, git, acl, delete

I've a quite big archive of git repositories in my development path, and many of them contains branches or stashes that I may have not published around.

However I want to be sure that for no reason I end up deleting a folder and it's .git folder, while I indeed want to be able to write on it.

So wondering if there's such way to achieve this.

Basically here it is:

```
repo
├── .git
│   ├── config
│   ├── index
.   .
.   .
.   .
```

I would love to protect `.git` from removal when doing `rm -rf repo`, but ensure that I can still access in read-write mode to both the `.git/config` file (and friends) and be able to write a new file to `.git/` itself.

Is there any way? I tried few hacks so far but none gave me such thing. Maybe using mounts could help with it more, but I would like to keep it stored all in the same place.

Comment: I am not sure you can both keep modifications rights and in the same time forbid removal.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`rm-protection`](https://github.com/alanzchen/rm-protection)

Install it by running:-

```bash
$ pip install rm-protection
```

The program's binary is `rm-p`. For convenience, add an alias:-

```bash
$ echo 'alias rm="rm-p"' >> ~/.bashrc
```

Since you want to protect the `.git` folder, run:-

```bash
$ protect .git
Question for .git: Do you really want to delete me?
Answer: Yes, I really do
```

You need to give it a security question and answer
Then when you try to delete it:-

```bash
$ rm -rf .git/
rm-p: .git: Do you really want to delete me?
Answer: No
rm-p: Wrong answer! .git will not be removed
```

This program works by creating a `..git.rm-protection` file with the question and answer in it.

Hope this helps ;)

Comment: This is a good suggestion, but the best thing you can do is to backup your projects (rclone, cron jobs, rsync, etc)

Comment: @sujay-r Well, this works, even though it's not really something that depends on the FS only, but can be acceptable.

Comment: @RobertSmith Indeed I'm making backups but that's not enough at times.